# Mysql extension removed in php 7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I have a quick question on the mysql extension, I have client who does not want to update the code in their site and is currently using mysql function such as `mysql_query` I know this has now been removed in PHP 7, I would like to know what occurs to this clients page due to much of these functions being deprecated or removed? Will it just eventually stop working properly? I am trying to make queries using this functions per their instruction but am not receiving the proper results so I was thinking this might be because of the outdated code. Any feed back welcomed.

Comment: the real question is; is that server running on php 7? if so, they can't use the `mysql_` api anymore.

Comment: *"I would like to know what occurs to this clients page due to much of these functions being deprecated or removed?"* - again; if on php 7, the latter will indeed have kicked in, and in turn having to rewrite everything to either the `mysqli_` or PDO api. *"Will it just eventually stop working properly?"* - Yes.